# How can I form commands in multisensor networks?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dynamic, sensors, rule-engine

Certain commands need to be sent out to sensors. I want to have one sensor class that represents a group of sensors. The idea is, during instantiation to link this sensor object with the set of commands that it should use. Eg. Two temperature sensors from different vendor would be represented by the same class but linked to different sets of commands.

I want to hide the complexity of the command from the user so the user only calls a method like getTemp() or setMaxTemp(20) without passing the command.

Challenge:

Let’s say there is a new temp sensor that only supports setMaxTemp(). In this case I will use a different sensor class but I still want to use the set max temperature command that is already stored. And/or maybe the same command set with different manipulation on the data.

So we have:
1. Sensor class 2. Command set 3. Data 4. Data manipulation

Question:

Linking dynamically these to form the correct request String and sending it to the correct sensor class took me a couple of days and I have not yet come up with a good approach with the conventional Java approach.

Do I need to go for rule engines? (Since the application will run in Raspberry Pi I’m not sure if it can handle it). Or is there a certain pattern to handle this kind of scenario? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find your question formulated a little unclear. Would you mind adding a more extensive example?

Comment: I thought that sensors only "sensed" (=generated readings). If your sensor can process setMaxTemp(20), then it seems to be actually controlling the temperature, and is no longer a simple sensor.

Comment: You need to add actual examples of a) what the user would see and b) what your program would generate; otherwise the question can be interpreted in a lot of different ways.

Comment: @tucuxi by setMaxTemp I was refering to set the threshold. Some sensors send alarm when threshold is passed but this is just an example anyway. The main issue is to make the commands usable by many sensor classes.

Answer (score 2):

So, there seems to be a **Sensor** interface being described.

```
public interface Sensor {
  int getTemp()
  void setMaxTemp()
  //etc.
}
```

You could also have an **AbstractSensor** class that provides naive implementations of the methods in the Sensor interface.

```
public abstract class AbstractSensor() {
  private int _temp = 0;
  private int _maxTemp = 0;

  @Override
  public int getTemp() { return _temp; }

  @Override
  public void setMaxTemp(int maxTemp) { _maxTemp = maxTemp; }

  //etc.
}
```

Then, you can create your individual sensor classes as either implementing Sensor or extending AbstractSensor (if they can't implement all methods).

```
public BrandASensor implements Sensor {
//Implementation here...
}

public BrandFSensor extends AbstractSensor {
//Implementation here
...
```

}